# Tkinter grid_columnfigure not working in Frame widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using `.grid()` to position things into a `Frame`. However, when I use `.grid_columnconfigure()` to make the column within that `Frame` resize to the window, it does absolutely nothing. To make matters more confusing, replacing `menu.grid_columnconfigure()` with `root.grid_columnconfigure()` indeed makes the column resize - so it seems as though the `Label` isn't being packed into the `Frame`, but `root` instead.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

menu = Frame(root)
menu.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
l = Label(menu,text="Main menu")

menu.grid()
l.grid(column=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `menu.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`, it affects the children that are added to the menu, not the menu in the root window.

If you want the menu frame to fill the window, you need to configure the rows and columns in its parent, and also set the `sticky` attribute so that it fills the space allocated to it.

If you're trying to affect the children of the inner frame, it is working as documented. It doesn't look like it's working because `menu` is shrinking to fit the label. The first column does indeed take up all of the extra space in `menu`, but `menu` doesn't have any extra space because of how it's added to the root window.

You can see this fairly easily by giving `menu` a distinctive color. You'll see that in your original code the frame is invisible because it shrinks to fit its contents.

[image: screenshot of original code with red menu]

When I configure the rows and columns of the root window, and then request that the menu fill the root window, you can now see that column 0 inside `menu` is indeed taking up all of the space.

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
...
menu.grid(sticky="nsew")
```

[image: screenshot after configuring root window]

Comment: I think you misunderstand; I am *trying* to affect the children of the menu frame, and it isn't doing that. I don't care if the menu frame fills the window.

The label within the menu frame is intended to occupy a column (of the menu frame itself) with a weight of 1.

Comment: @SkyShoesmith Since you didn't configure the weight of the root window, the frame is doing to shrink down to the size of its contents. The problem isn't that the column isn't configured in the frame, it's that the frame isn't filling the window.